# Electron: Prevent middle click

Tags: javascript, electron

In Electron, it is possible to use the following to open links in the web browser and not in Electron with `left click`:

```
const {shell} = require('electron')
function openUrl(e) {
    var e = window.e || e;
    if (e.target.localName == 'a') {
        e.preventDefault();
        shell.openExternal(e.target.href);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('click', openUrl, false);
```

However, `click` does not work for `middle mouse` button. `mousedown` and `mouseup` open the link in both a new Electron window and in the web browser (probably because it fires after a new Electron window is created).

How do I stop a link opening a new Electron window with `middle click` in Electron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got to use `auxclick` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/auxclick) it handles all non-left clicks and is the key event for creating the electron window via middle mouse. This code is for the **render** process within a preload script or enabled `nodeIntegration`

```js
const { shell } = require('electron')

function auxclickHandler(event) {
    if (e.target.localName == 'a') {
        event.preventDefault();
        shell.openExternal(url);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('auxclick', callback, false)
```

---

An *alternative* if you want to redirect **any** type of link to the internal browser. This code is for the **main process**

Here a fiddle for Electron Fiddle https://gist.github.com/Hammster/ce4fac29deaf3600665d9534e3a32317

```js
const { shell } = require('electron')

mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function (event, url) {
    event.preventDefault()
    shell.openExternal(url)
})
```

Comment: this solution not working now 
 **electron v6.0.9**

Comment: tested it with electron fiddle just now, _it works_ with 6.0.9 and 6.0.10. Are you sure you added this code into the render script?

Comment: New window still showing if we click links inside **iframe** component see this [fiddle](https://gist.github.com/62ecfb12dccd28be90961529ec609c76)

Comment: I frames run isolated, you sadly cannot change this with remote pages at all (because of CORS). My solution also does not take this into consideration, i'm adding a alternative that covers any link redirect.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel you can use the new example for general link handling :)